# ERROR 1813 (HY000) at line x: Tablespace '`mydb`.`mytable`' exists

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm starting off with a fresh mysql-server installation and am trying to import data into it. I do `CREATE DATABASE mydb;` and then do the following:

```
mysql mydb < mydb_schema.sql
```

mydb_schema.sql was generated by doing `mysqldump mydb --no-data > mydb_schema.sql`.

The problem is that `mysql mydb < mydb_schema.sql` is stopping midway through with the following error:

```
ERROR 1813 (HY000) at line x: Tablespace '`mydb`.`mytable`' exists.
```

Here's what's in the `mydb_schema.sql` file:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mytable`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Those are the only two times `mytable` is referenced in that file. Further, the word "`TABLESPACE`" does not occur in that file.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21692066/569976 doesn't really seem applicable since this is a from scratch import idk.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @RickJames - It was an issue on 5.6 and 5.7. But I figured out the issue - it was an issue with there being two tables with different cases.

Comment: (I was chasing the "tablespace" part of the question.  No, I don't have anything to add.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently there were two copies of `mytable` in my DB dump. There was `mytable` (all lowercase) and `MyTable` (camel case). On Linux that's not an issue but I guess on Mac OS X it is an issue.